# Mysterious python behaviour

Tags: python, string, sequences

Im trying to write a quick script to output a sequence.
The sequence begins is as follows:
1,11,21,1211,111221,312211...
starts with 1, then as 1 1 the second term is 11, as two 1s third term is then 21's ect.

I have written a script below which outputs the terms in this sequence.
It outputs the correct next term when the input_string is 1, ie 11. But ALL terms after then output as 11 too..... if I manually set the input to 11, then all the terms are calculated correctly.

This makes no sense, as with the initial input of `"1"` my `total_sequence[0]` variable will be `"1"`, giving the correct output of `"11"`. 
The next term will then have `total_sequence[1]` as its input, which is `"11"` i.e. the last iterations output. 
But this gives `"11"` as its output. 
If I directly put `"11"` in as the total_sequence[1] term instead of referencing `total_sequence[1]` ( which = `"11"`) then the correct output is then given.

So basically why is `input_string = "11"` different to `output[1]` where `output = ["1","11"]`?

```
input_string= "1"
N=5
total_sequence = [input_string]

for i in xrange(0,N,1):    
    N_counter = int(0)
    previous_char = ""
    output_string = ""
    character_index = int(1)

    #loop through each character in the current sequence term
    for current_char in total_sequence[i]:
        #if first character
        if  character_index == 1:
            N_counter = 1
        #if last character
        if character_index == len(input_string):
            if current_char == previous_char:
                N_counter = N_counter + 1

            if current_char != previous_char:
                if previous_char!="":
                    output_string  = output_string + str( N_counter ) + str( previous_char )
                N_counter = int( 1 )    
            output_string  = output_string + str( N_counter ) + str( current_char )

        #if neither first nor last character
        if character_index != 1 and character_index != len(input_string) :
            if current_char == previous_char:
                N_counter = N_counter + 1

            if current_char != previous_char:
                output_string  = output_string + str( N_counter ) + str( previous_char )
                N_counter = int( 1 )

        character_index = character_index + 1
        previous_char = current_char

    total_sequence.append( output_string)  

print total_sequence
```

Comment: This seems like a question from the Python Challenge.

Comment: Well, It very well may be. I had never heard of the python challenge until your comment. I obtained the sequence from a friends book of puzzles, where the puzzle was to estimate the number of characters in the nth term of this sequence.

Comment: It is a classic puzzle series, you may find it in the Python Challenge but also in a ton of books about puzzles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `input_string` in the body of your loop, but that is never changed, it is always the very first string, in your example `"1"`.

Probably changing the first line of the inner loop with:

```
input_string = total_sequence[i]
for current_char in input_string:
```

should be enough, but I didn't test it.

Comment: Well I certainly feel like an idiot now. 
Thank you rodrigo for your sharp eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the "look and say" sequence; it could be implemented much more simply using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def look_and_say(n):
    """
    Generate the first `n` terms of the sequence
      '1', '11', '21', '1211', ...
    """
    if n < 1:
        return

    # first term
    term = "1"
    yield term

    # second through `n`th terms
    for term_num in range(1, n):
        chars = []
        for ch,reps in groupby(term):
            count = len(list(reps))
            chars.append(str(count))
            chars.append(ch)
        term = "".join(chars)
        yield term
```

then

```
N = 5
print(list(look_and_say(N)))
```

gives

```
['1', '11', '21', '1211', '111221']
```

Fun bonus: prove that the sequence will never include a digit higher than 3.